# How to scrapy data move to next page using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like scrape data https://www.arduinothai.com/category/2/arduino-compatible-board using python 3.5 and BeautifulSoup. I can succesfully scrape the data on first page, but I can not  able to scrape data from the other pages. This is my code

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

URL='https://www.arduinothai.com/category/2/arduino-compatible-board'
Request=requests.get(URL)
soups=BeautifulSoup(Request.text,'lxml')

''' Find All page in website
Count_Next_Pages = soups.find_all('span','tsk-all')
TotalProduct = int(Count_Next_Pages[1].text)
TotalProductPerPage = 40
TotalPages = (round(TotalProduct/TotalProductPerPage))

count=0
for i in range(int(TotalPages)):
    count+=1
    i='https://www.arduinothai.com/category/2/arduino-compatible-board?tskp='+str(count)
    Request_Data=requests.get(i)
    Soups_Data=BeautifulSoup(Request_Data.text,'lxml')
    AllProduct=Soups_Data.find_all('div',class_='productDetail')

for x in AllProduct:
     AllProductDeatil = x.find('a').get("gaeepd") 
     IDProductLink = json.loads(AllProductDeatil)["id"]  

    #Scrape ProductID
     ProductID = x.find('span','code').get_text(strip=True)
     pattren = r'[A-Z]{2}\d{5}|\d{5}|....\d{5}'          
     regex = re.compile(pattren)
     ProDuctIDResult = regex.findall(ProductID)  
     ProductIDStr = ConvertListToStr(ProDuctIDResult)
     ProductIDAll.append(ProductIDStr)   

   #Scrape Stock    
     URL_Prefix =requests.get('https://www.arduinothai.com/product/'+str(IDProductLink))
     SoupStock = BeautifulSoup(URL_Prefix.text, 'lxml')   
     ChkStock = SoupStock.find('span', class_='num').text
     StockOfProduct.append(ChkStock)

     if((ProductCategory_jsonData==('Single Set')) or (ProductCategory_jsonData==('Triple Set')) or (ProductCategory_jsonData==('STM32'))):

         ListOfProduct.append((ProductIDStr, NameOfProduct, PriceOfProduct, OldProPricesStr, ChkStock, Link_URL, ProductCategory_jsonData))

         data_df = pd.DataFrame({
                'ProductID': ProductIDAll,
                'ProdcutName':Productname,
                'Productprice':Productprice,
                'OldProductPrice': OldProductPrice,
                'StockOfProduct': StockOfProduct,
                'Link': LinkProduct,
                'Category':CategoryProduct
         })

     df=pd.DataFrame(ListOfProduct, columns=['ProductID', 'ProductName','Discount','Price','Stock','Link','TypeOfProduct'])
     pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
df
```

Comment: Could you give the error that you are seeing?

Comment: @alpha1554 he is trying to scrap 2 pages one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the code for the two page urls:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
for i in [1,2]:
    URL='https://www.arduinothai.com/category/2/arduino-compatible-board?tskp=' + str(i)
    Request=requests.get(URL)
    soups=BeautifulSoup(Request.text,'lxml')
    # your scrape here
```